# How do I use the persistent volume of one container as a volume mount of another container?

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a container which is basically a directory containing configuration files. These configuration files will be used by another container which contains the application executables.
Both the containers are deployed in the same pod.

I have created the pv and pvc for the 1st container like -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: app-pvc
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  volumeName: app-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Next I am creating the deployment of both the containers like -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: app
  strategy:
     type: Recreate
  template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: app
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: lshome
           image: <local_registry>/container1:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           volumeMounts:
              - name: container1-persistant-storage
                mountPath: /home/app/config
         - name: wildfly
           image: <local_registry>/container2:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           volumeMounts:
              - name: container1-config
                mountPath: /home/app/config                 
       volumes:
        - name: container1-persistant-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
        - name: container1-config
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
```

What I want is that the data under /home/app/config directory in container 1 be available to container 2 at the same directory structure. I have created the same directory structure in container 2 as well.

When I am trying to create the deployment, its giving the message - Unable to attach or mount volumes and then not able to create the deployment.

Comment: Can you use a ConfigMap to hold the configuration files?  What is the actual program running in the container that has the configuration?

Comment: Are you using a single node, or multiple nodes? It looks like the [ReadWriteOnce](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) volumes can be mounted as read-write by a single node.

Comment: Its a single node cluster. There are no programs running on the configuration container. It's just a simple directory containing the configuration files. The issue is resolved if I do not create the 1st container but simply use the pvc in the 2nd container. But I still want to know as to how to copy the data from one container to another. Is initContainers the only option ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't define two volumes, delete **container1-config** and it works. Like below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: app
  strategy:
     type: Recreate
  template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: app
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: lshome
           image: <local_registry>/container1:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           volumeMounts:
              - name: container1-persistant-storage
                mountPath: /home/app/config
         - name: wildfly
           image: <local_registry>/container2:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           volumeMounts:
              - name: container1-persistant-storage
                mountPath: /home/app/config                 
       volumes:
        - name: container1-persistant-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add further insights to your problem. The reason of failures of mounting volume is because two different containers **lshome** and **wildfly** are trying to mount the same writeable storage.

By the time when **lshome** container is created, it already claims and bounds the storage/PV using the **app-pvc** claimName request thereby, does not allow the other container **wildfly** to request another storage or mount the already mounted storage/pv as it has already been bound by that time with the first container.

So, the solution to your problem here is:

**1. Claim the storage/PV only once by declaring the PV only once as shown below:**

```
   volumes:
    - name: shared-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: app-pvc
```

**2. Call this PV (shared-storage) in all the containers' volumeMounts where you want this volume to be shared with as shown below:**

```
       volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-storage
            mountPath: /home/app/config
```

I would also suggest you taking a look at **"Mounting configMaps as Volumes"** in K8s as an alternative best practice to your approach. This way you can store all the App configuration files as configMaps objects in K8s and then mount those configMaps as volumes directly in multi-container Pods in order to make those App configurational files available to other containers within the same Pod.

URLs for reference:

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/mount-configmap-as-file-in-existing-directory/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/